# Java clob retrieval using getString - character encoding issue

Tags: java, oracle, character-encoding, clob

So I have a database with a table, where one of it's entries is '*é€áí*', and I know this is correct in the db. It is stored as a **clob**.

In Java, I retrieve the entry like so:

```
String text = resultSet.getString(DBConstants.COL_NOTE_TEXT);
```

When debugging, text is equal to '*é\u0080áí*' and when displayed on the screen the euro symbol is a square block.

Anyone seen this before? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's interesting, since the character U+0080 is the Unicode character "<control>" (so no surprises that it doesn't print).  A Euro symbol is actually U+20AC.  I've no actual ideas on why this might be happening but this might give you some clues...

Comment: FOrgot to mention - I am aware that \u0080 is the euro symbol, but why has it not just been converted to the euro symbol. If I do text.replaceAll("\u0080", "€"), all is god. But why do I have to? Cheers.

Comment: Oh ok! I thought I read somewhere that was the euro symbol...ok even more confused!

Comment: *How* do you know it's correct in the DB? In particular I've seen some rather odd behaviors where text that was inserted using some bizarro mechanism will actually appear correctly when you try to view it in the DB directly, depending on how you have it set up. For example, if you set your client NLS_LANG to UTF8 and view the data using a client (in my case PL/SQL Developer 6.5) that doesn't support UTF-8 it may look right even though it's not.

Comment: Oh, also, what JDBC driver are you using and what version of the database?

Comment: Thanks for your help. You may be right then, someone used SQL developer to check the entry and was returned correctly. Not sure if the client set NLS_LANG, will try and find out. Diver is 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' and think version is 10g, character encoding is win1252.

Comment: Wait a minute...your *database* character encoding is Windows-1252?

Comment: Yes, we also have a UTF-8 one that we are attempting to test it with although we need to create the schemas. Is this to be expected then if character encoding is windows-1252?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

[oracle-jdbc-euro-character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377745/oracle-jdbc-euro-character)

Think this is my problem. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

0080 is the euro character in the Windows Western encoding (cp-1252); in Unicode it is 20AC.  You may want to check the encoding of the input. The other thing to check is that the screen is capable of displaying the euro symbol.  If it will display '\u20AC' that part is answered.

Comment: Beat me to it, I was just writing that up. :-P

Comment: The problem could be that the DB is storing cp1252 data (in which case you change the Java type to BLOB), or it could be something related to the transfer of data (which has to be encoded into bytes).