# oracle euro character issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't register the euro character € in my oracle database. If I do it in request (in a .sql script) I have a -| symbol, if I do it directly in edition mode in sqldevelopper i have a point mark upside down. I have seen this similar question :
[oracle-jdbc-euro-character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377745/oracle-jdbc-euro-character)

But jdbc is not used in my process, my mistake.

Comment: What is your database version?

Comment: What character encoding is your DB set to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably to do with the CHARACTERSET used by your database. Run the following query to check your CHARACTERSET:

```
select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

The Euro symbol is supported by:

```
AL24UTFFSS
AR8MSWIN1256
BLT8MSWIN1257
CL8MSWIN1251
D8EBCDIC1141
DK8EBCDIC1142
EE8MSWIN1250
EL8ISO8859P7
EL8MSWIN1253
F8EBCDIC1147
I8EBCDIC1144
IW8MSWIN1255
S8EBCDIC1143
TR8MSWIN1254
UTF8
WE8EBCDIC1140
WE8EBCDIC1145
WE8EBCDIC1146
WE8EBCDIC1148
WE8ISO8859P15
WE8MSWIN1252
WE8PC858
```

For more information take a look at [Oracle Metalink Note 68790.1: RDBMS Support for the Euro Currency Symbol](http://metalink.oracle.com/metalink/plsql/showdoc?db=Not&id=68790.1).

Comment: Indeed we use the WE8ISO8859P1 one which does not support the € character